# PHP POSTing/submitting wrong information through forms

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm dynamically generating FORMS and every form has an ID as a GET variable. So let's say there are two forms:

```
<form action='website.com/controller?id=1'>
  <input type="submit" name="submitting">
</form>

<form action='website.com/controller?id=2'>
  <input type="submit" name="submitting">
</form>
```

Now, for some strange reasons, I see POST request, in my console, as:

```
http://website.com/controller?id=2
```

For both the forms. On submitting both the form I see the same POST request.

PS: I'm modifying one of Prestashop modules.

Comment: change each form 'name' to a unique value and test it then

Comment: @Sean i cannot do that. Like i said, these forms are generated dynamically.

Comment: The code you've provided, in isolation, will not have the behaviour you describe. I can't think of any way to get the effect you describe without JavaScript being involved. You need to provide a **complete** [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin you're right, I've got event listeners attached to each form that POST form data through Ajax. I need to dabble into one of these and then get back. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Quentin Your experience in this matter is clear, I see now looking at your comment that the above example is lacking enough context.

Comment: @chandlerbing What did you find?  Does anything here help, and if not, can you add the relevant parts of your JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding forms after page load, and using event handlers to submit them, you need to use event delegation.

Event handlers must be attached to elements that exist on page load.  You can't attach a handler to an element you dynamically add later, after page load.

The way around this problem is to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  For example:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    // This will handle any form which exists at page load.  Any form
    // dynamically added later will not be handled.
}

$('body').on('submit', '#someFormID', function(e) {
    // This is attached to the parent body element, which of course exists
    // on load, and will handle submission of anything in the body, even
    // those which did not exist at page load.  You can then filter to
    // match only elements matching the next parameter - eg in this case
    // handle only something with id 'someFormID'.
}

$('body').on('submit', function(e) {
    // You can also dynamically work out which form has been submitted
    var $button = $(e.target),
        $form = $button.closest('form'),
        action = $form.attr('action');
}
```

Comment: If the event handlers were not being associated with the forms, then they would submit to the URL their actions point to. Since they don't, the JavaScript must be binding to the forms.

Comment: @Quentin Possibly, but not if the URL is retrieved via jQuery, eg `$(this).attr('action')`, where `$(this)` is unexpectedly referring to the wrong `form`. We really need to see the existing Javascript.

Comment: There are *lots* of ways that JavaScript could be written that would resolve in the wrong URL being used. The question needs a [mcve] before it is answerable without wild speculation.

Comment: So there are `lots of ways` my answer could be correct ... and yet you downvoted and suggest it is not.  I guess we're both wildly speculating! :-)

Comment: I'm not declaring that my speculation is a complete solution (i.e. an answer) to the problem. The OP needs to provide a [mcve] before a good answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<form action='website.com/controller' method='get'> 
<Input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'>
<input type="submit" name="submitting"> </form>
 <form action='website.com/controller' method='get'> 
<Input type='hidden' name='id' value='2'>
<input type="submit" name="submitting"> </form>
```

Comment: Why should it work? The problem reported in the question was that neither the action nor the method were being respected. How does this fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I thank everyone for taking the time.

Final Step: I figured I cannot use Ajax, because every time I POST, it gets the `id` of last generated `form` So if there are `n` number of forms, POST for every submit button will look like:

```
http://website.com/controller?id=n
```

If it was only about 1 form, it wouldn't have been a problem. But since `form` occurrences are dependable, AJAX fails.

BTW, here's the Ajax code I've been using:

```
jQuery('form[name=someclass]).submit(function(e){
$.ajax({
        url: $('form[name=st_blog_comment_form]').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form[name=someclass]').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(json){}
 )};
```

Or perhaps, I've not been using ajax properly.

Comment: If you want to get it working, please have a look at my answer.  The jQuery code you've shown suffers from exactly the problem I describe.  Your selector will only handle any forms that exist on page load - not anything added dynamically later.  Additionally, they'll all POST to the same, single URL, as the selector you use to find the URL will match only your `st_blog_comment_form` form, not the one you are currently submitting.  Try my code, and let me know if you have any questions - you're almost there! :-)

Comment: On page load, every single form (which are dynamically generated) exists, with their `form` easily be inspected in dev tools.

Answer (score -1):

When we execute the code you will be getting two submit button, the first one is for first form and second is for second form. for each form there is respective action specified in form tag as method is not defined in the form tag by default it will consider this as a request GET and you can access the submit values by using $_REQUEST or $_GET. if you need a secure way you can try with POST and access thous values by $_POST.

Ex: if we are executing the above form in php test folder and submit you will getting like this like
http://localhost/test/website.com/controller?submitting=Submit

If you create the same thing in html and submit for the folder path "website.com/controller?submitting=Submit" this will be appended.

For preventing auto submission you can add an hidden token in the form.

Comment: This appears to be some random facts about forms which *does not explain the behaviour described in the question or solve the problem being described*.

Comment: You are right, I neglected to read the question and postulate his issue correctly, as mentioned before I made assumptions based the incomplete context and my failure to properly comprehend this: "Now, for some strange reasons, I see POST request, in my console, as:

http://website.com/controller?id=2" which clearly indicates he is not directly submitting the forms via HTTP, if he was his issue could not be what he has described.  I've deleted my entire answer.